# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, imageview, android-linearlayout, inflate-exception

Im new with android.

I am developing an app for a Commercial Kitchen Equipment supplier. I am particularly having problems on one section. this activity products_1.xml layout resource file. I have created a linear layout with the products as ImageView. The ImageView is clickable. There are 12 such images in the LinearLayout. The activity works fine on phones that have smaller display settings (icons and text). But on phones with normal display or large display this activity has errors and the app crashes. Logcat shows error on line #55, i.e ImageView android:id="@+id/Commercial_six", and when i change the image src for that ImageView and all the ones below to images for the first three ImageView, the app works fine.

So I know the problem is with the layout resource products_1.xml.

Logcat

```
01-20 09:42:43.018 7878-7878/com.example.aaron.imageapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.aaron.imageapp, PID: 7878
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aaron.imageapp/com.example.aaron.imageapp.Product_1}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
                                                                          at com.example.aaron.imageapp.Product_1.onCreate(Product_1.java:19)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                          at com.example.aaron.imageapp.Product_1.onCreate(Product_1.java:19) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                          at com.example.aaron.imageapp.Product_1.onCreate(Product_1.java:19) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4632612 byte allocation with 2430288 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
                                                                          at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                          at com.example.aaron.imageapp.Product_1.onCreate(Product_1.java:19) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

product_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_Chinese_Gas"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/product_commercial_chinese_burner" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_Single_Burner"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/product_commercial_single_burner" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_Two_Burner"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/product_commercial_two_burner" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_four"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/products_commercial_four_burner_continental" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_six"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/products_commercial_six_burner" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_tilting_boiling"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/products_commercial_tilting_boiling_pan" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_tilting_bratts"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/products_commercial_tilting_bratts" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_mobile_tandoor"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/products_commercial_mobile_tandoor" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_mobile_shwarma"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/products_commercial_shawerma" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_mobile_automatic_chapatti_maker"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/products_commercial_automatic_chapati" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_automatic_chapati_rolling"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/products_commercial_automatic_chapati_roling" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Commercial_mobile_chapati_plate"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/products_commercial_chapati_plate" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're inflating the correct layout file? Line 55 in product_1.xml is `android:layout_width="350dp"` within an `ImageView`, not a component declaration. This sort of error normally occurs on the first line of a declaration.

Comment: Actually line 55 is <ImageView for android:id="@+id/Commercial_six. The line numbers might have changed when I put the code here. So here it will be line 53, in the snippet i put here.Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

It seems that you are using images with high resolution which make your app crashes.

Use recycler view to display your images instead of having too many image views in same page.